# messaging_postbacks webhook events (Messenger) in Oracle's skill bots

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

So, I have managed to get my bot up and running on Facebook Messenger. I recently added the persistent_menu but now I can't figure out how to respond to those menu click postback events on Oracle Cloud's Skill bot. Can anyone guide me to the right place in the docs where I can get help?

I wish to activate a particular state of the Bot skill in reaction to the menu button click.

Comment: Please post some code in order for us to be able to help.

Comment: @EricHauenstein, It's the Oracle Cloud SaaS and Messenger Profile API, the only code I have written is for my custom component in the Embedded Container. That, however is not directly related to what I am inquiring. I just need someone to show me how to detect those postback events on Cloud's Skill bot.